Anticommutator of wedge product and interior product
Here is a nice question.
Consider a Euclidean vector space $V$ and denote by $e_v$ (resp. $i_v$) the endomorphism on $\Lambda^*V$ defined by $e_v\omega = v\wedge\omega$ (resp. $i_v= \iota_{v^*}$, where $\iota$ denotes the interior product defined by $v^*\in V^*$. Here, $v^*$ denotes the metric dual to $v$, e.g. ''musical isomorphism''.). Show that $$e_vi_u+i_ue_v = (u,v)\cdot\mathrm{Id}_{\Lambda^kV}$$ for all $u,v\in V$. This seems like an exercise in linear algebra but it has nice applications in Geometric Analysis. E.g., with this result, one can show that the Hodge-De Rham operator is elliptic. I am wondering on how to prove this result. I was thinking about fixing an orthonormal basis in $V$ and dual basis in $V^*$. Any help or hints towards literature is appreciated. - Thanks
Edit: This result is somehow associated to Cartan.

Both sides are bilinear in $u,v$, so doesn’t it indeed follow immediately by choosing an orthonormal basis for $V$ and considering the general basis element for $\Lambda^k$?

You can find related formulas in the complex case on pp. 111-113 of Griffiths and Harris.

A basic property of the interior product is that it is an antiderivation with respect to (co)vectors: for any $\omega\in V^*$ and $X,Y\in{\bigwedge}V$ $$i_\omega(X\wedge Y) = i_\omega(X)\wedge Y + \hat X\wedge i_\omega(Y)$$ where $X\to\hat X$ is the unique extension of $v\mapsto -v : V\to V$ to an automorphism of ${\bigwedge}V$.
Letting $\omega=u^*$, $X = v$, and $Y$ arbitrary proves your identity.
The above property is essentially used to define the interior product in Werner Greub's Multilinear Algebra (1967). You could also prove it using the determinant formula for the natural pairing between ${\bigwedge}V^*$ and ${\bigwedge}V$, $$\langle\omega_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge\omega_k,\:v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_l\rangle = \delta_{kl}\det\Bigl(\omega_i(v_j)\Bigr)_{i,j=1}^k,$$ and the fact that the interior product is the adjoint of the exterior product under this pairing, $$\langle\Psi,i_\omega(X\wedge Y)\rangle = \langle\omega\wedge\Psi,X\wedge Y\rangle.$$

Thank you, but how do I show that the interior product is the adjoint of the wedge product? Is it just brute force choice of basis with subsequence computation to verify the equality or is there some neat trick with which one can succeed?

@Mathematicsenthusiast It all depends on what your definition of the interior product is.

@Nickolas Todoroff, I will divert a little from the notation used in my question as I copied the question from the literature on geometric analysis, where it was posed as an exercise. Suppose $\alpha_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\alpha_k,\beta_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\beta_k\in\bigwedge^kV$. Then define $\langle\alpha_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\alpha_k,\beta_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\beta_k\rangle:=\mathrm{det}(\langle\alpha_i,\beta_j\rangle)$, where the $\alpha_i$,$\beta_j$ are 1-forms and the scalar product on 1-forms is defined by fixing a basis in $V$ and considering its dual basis.

I believe the definition is the one you provided above. In this case, I think I should do brute force computation w.r.t. my chosen basis.

@Mathematicsenthusiast If you're referring to the determinant formula, that does not constitute a definition of the interior product. The interior product is equal to the inner product when its multiplicands have the same grade, but this doesn't say anything about what happens when they have different grades. If you're referring to the antiderivation definition, then proving the adjoint formula does not require any bases or really any brute force; it's essentially just a single Laplace expansion of the determinant along a row.
